# What are alternative methods to Fluid for making a glass appear to be full of liquid?

Tags: texturing, particles, fluid-simulation

> What are alternative methods to Fluid for making a glass appear to be full of liquid?

I just require a quick simple method. I was going to use particles but wondered if anyone had other methods or ideas.
Doesn't need to be too realistic as it's only for a small static image project.

Comment: does it need to be animated?

Comment: No not animated at all.

Answer (score 4):

One way is by simply creating a face for the surface of the liquid, and then use separate materials on each interface as in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2823/599).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about if the glass container were an odd shape?

Comment: @FoxyFish It's still the same idea, you just have to figure out how to make a face from the glass (extrude and merge works well). For most shapes it shouldn't be hard, but I can't give any more detail without knowing what the shape in question is.

Comment: You can select an edge loop (add one if needed) near the water level. Shift-D to duplicate the verts and E to extrude scaling inwards to fill in the surface. This will give you a water surface to match any shape.

Comment: @sambler Unless you have a really strange shape like a jug with a hollow handle or something. Another thing to remember is to add a little surface tension to the liquid surface too.