# How to create this type of gradient background lighting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

How to create this kind of lighting in blender?

[image: Lighting]

This image itself was create from blender!
But whenever I try to make this kind of lighting I always get **all white results** like this,

[image]

Can anyone help me with it? :)
Just the light setup.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24110/how-should-a-glass-material-be-setup-in-cycles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this you can use a textured emission plane (you could [simulate it with an out of focus mesh lamp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32861/599) too, but a plane will be less noisy).

1. Add a big plane behind your scene:

   [image]
2. Give it a procedural gradient material:

   [image]

   The [*Object* coordinates](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html#texture-coordinates) are centered around the object's [*Origin*](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/transformations/transform_control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html#in-object-mode), so by default that's where the gradient will be centered.

   To adjust the size and scale of the gradient, you can tweak the settings on the *[Mapping node](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/more.html#mapping)*

   I've also made the plane brighter than it appears to the camera by using different emission shaders based on the [*Camera Ray*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html#ray-visibility) output of the [*Light Path*](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html#light-path) node, to avoid over exposing the background a lot.
3. Render

   [image]

This way glossy floor plane will reflect the light from the plane, creating a neat effect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The secret is about compositing, not lighting.
I've made a simple scene just to give you an idea.
2 render layers, with transparent background.
The first is a background plane textured with a gradient shader, spherical.
The second is a plane, diffuse and glossy (lot of glossiness), with a glass on it (simple glass)
Light is a single sun with a light blue color.

[image: 3D scene]

only first layer

[image]

only second layer
[image]

Composite!
[image]

Compositing  nodes setup, for further tweaking
[image]

Comment: You could alternatively do in in a way that doesn't need two render layers; you could render the glass using transparent film, then overlay it on a blurred ellipse mask with an "Alpha Over" node.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but i did like the reflections of the background on the glossy plane!

Comment: Oh right, that looks nice!