# Weird texture problem with glass

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to make a posion, however, when I try and aim the camera,it still shows the wood, not sure what's causing it. [image]

[image]

Comment: Hi gabe. 1: your glass wall have zero thickness. 2: this is predictable behaviors, because glass reflect wood texture and also there are glass refraction

Comment: 1:  other words: you made one solid glass object. You have no empty space in the bottle.

Comment: @gabe  add a solidify modifer

Comment: Related liks worth reading: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24110/how-should-a-glass-material-be-setup-in-cycles/24148#24148

Answer (score 1):

The answer was from Subol, he said that it wasn't thick enough, to make it "thicker", add a solidify modifier.