# Realistic lighting for a translucent liquid

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I tried to make like this lighting in blender by adding area lights in two sides, with orange color and with HDRI, but I couldn't achieve what I want. Any tips?
.
Thank you
.
.

[image]

Comment: To help you better please show images of your current  lighting setup and the nodes for your material.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24110/how-should-a-glass-material-be-setup-in-cycles/24148#24148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass/35741#35741