# Help with putting liquid in glass in blender

Tags: modeling, rendering

I'm trying to make a beer in a glass in blender, and I am having an issue. I went to render it after I put the liquid in the glass to see how it looked, and the beer part (which is a separate object) is showing up in the bottom of the glass where it shouldn't. Can anyone help? By the way, I am very new to blender. If it helps, I was following the tutorial on blenderguru.com.
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-beer-blender/[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3 How do I do this?

Comment: See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/658/599

Comment: Maybe the bottom part of the glass is too reflective, have you tried mixing your glossy shader with a glass shader and have to bump up the value for glass? Or did you accidentally assign a material to the bottom part of the Glass?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1031" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1031/)

Comment: Instead of modeling the glass and liquid as discrete entities, you might instead try modeling the *interfaces* between them. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35741/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2823/599

Answer (score 2):

In your file the liquid object and the glass object both have the same material. If you give the glass object a separate material without any absorption, it works as expected.

1. With the glass selected, make a copy of the beer material by clicking the `2` icon:

   [image]
2. Remove the absorption node (<kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>):

   [image]

Comment: Strangely my example below use absorption for both the liquid and glass. Seems to work fine.

Comment: @hawkenfox Even with the same color and density?

Comment: @ gandalf3 no admittedly I have 2 absorption material not like the one OP have posted. I have 1 for the glass and a another for the drink but it's both absorption enabled.

Comment: @hawkenfox Ah, I see. Like you say, there's nothing wrong with having absorption on both. The OP's issue is having the *exact same material* on both. If you want beer-colored glass, well, that's what the OP has :P

Answer (score -1):

One of the way to do this is to make sure the liquid object is inside the glass object ever so slightly. Meaning the liquid object is a little larger than the internal surface of the glass object. So **SCALE UP** your liquid object by say "1.001" or "1.01"

This should be the result you get.

[image]

BLEND FILE EXAMINATION

Examined your blend file and found gaps between the glass and the liquid object. My suggestion is that you should apply the sub surf modifier on the glass and create the liquid beer object from the interior polygon surface of the glass object. Remember to flip your normals on the beer liquid object using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Then scale it up so that you do not have 2 sub surf modifier on 2 separate mesh which you may have accidentally changed and mismatching their geometry.

Comment: I tried that. It made it worse. I'm pretty sure my liquid is outside my glass, but I'm not sure. I uploaded my blender file in a comment so hopefully that would help.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1031" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1031/)

Comment: So I should re-make the liquid?

Comment: If you want it to look perfect. As it stands now, your liquid object and beer object's geometry are not matching up perfectly. You might have adjusted the base mesh of the liquid object after you duplicate them from the glass object by accident. What I usually do is to get the mesh directly from the glass object with applied sub surf mesh so there is no difference and scale it up from there.