# Tinted glass for a helmet

Tags: rendering, shaders, glass

I have this character with a helmet.

I want to see his face clearly through the glass and see clear reflections from the environment

I also want it to have an orange tint.

something like this:

Clear see through glass, clear reflections
[image: Clear see through glass, clear reflections]

And tinted color

[image]

This is how far I came:

I tried shader with glass and shader with transparant and glossy combined with a diffuse shader.

With a HDR and a sun lamp.

Not really reflective maybe?

[image]

Kinda better I guess but a little dark and now has double reflections?

[image]

With this shader:
[How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And volume aborbtion but still double reflection?
[image]

I appreciate any help

Comment: Read: [How to illuminate the darkness inside glass objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Comment: For color on a glass object use volume absorption with the color you need and plug it to the volume socket of the shader output. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60413/how-to-make-liquids-color-intensity-less-where-the-geometry-is-thinner and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76262/1853

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I copied the shader and it looks pretty good but i still have 2 reflections even though the object isnt that thick. And if i dont give it thickness its working like a lens. any thoughts?

Comment: Yes without thickness the glass will be a solid marble. Double reflection is part of any glass (look closely at any window in the real world). Each layer of glass (I presume you are thinking of a sliding tinted glass that moves in front of the transparent one)  will bring in two reflections or more, as the reflections of one layer are reflected on the other glass. If you absolutely must have only one reflection play with inverting the normals on the back surface of the object.

Comment: I agree but why is the distnace now greater? In the other render it was closer together now it's distance looks doubled. Also I don't see a double reflection in the first reference image. Now I'm just curious :)