# Creating water in a glass

Tags: mesh, vertices

another newbie question...
I have created a glass in this way: pic2-4. 
Then I tried to create water in it by duplicating an inner layer and making it a separate object: pic 1-5.
The problem is: when I extrude the top vertex to create a water surface (as I duplicated an inner layer after I created a glass and deleted a top vertex in it) I cannot close the hole in the surface. Also, there are grey shadows, which I suppose shouldn't have appeared.
Maybe there is another way to create static water?[image]
The file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxt3xajio75if1o/file1.blend?dl=0

Comment: Have you tried selecting the vertices that make up the inner circle and pressing ALT+"M" and choosing Collapse from the drop down menu?

Comment: I created both glass and water from such frames with an invisible pivot in the centre and application of a screw modifier, thus I have only one curve with points, that I can edit...

Comment: Please host your files using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ If the link to your file disappears the question will not be as useful to others.

Comment: @Maria please read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass

Answer (score 2):

Select the vertex you extruded, and bring out the *Properties* panel (hit <kbd>N</kbd> or click *View* -> *Properties*). Under *Transform*, make sure *Local* is set, then manually set the X and Y coordinates to 0, but leave the Z coordinate as is. This will adjust the vertex's position to right above the object's origin, without moving it up or down.

[image]

Strictly speaking, the hole is still there after this, but it has a size of 0, but it may become visible again after subdividing, as this may also move some vertices. To remove it altogether, you need to click *Apply* in the screw modifier, then go into edit mode and remove double vertices. To do this, select everything by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> as many times as needed, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>D</kbd> or click *Mesh* -> *Vertices* -> *Remove Doubles*.

Answer (score 0):

In volume absorption increase rgb value to 1 and u will have no longer grey shadows in water
[image: increase rgb all value to 1][image: rgb value increased to 1]

Answer (score -1):

hi there try to move in x direction nd u will have no longer hole on top
 [image: in x direction]

[image: no there is no hole]

Comment: I tried but it remains. When I move the vertex towards the centre, the hole diminishes but doesn't dissapear. Then, when the vertex crosses the hole, it just starts growing again...

Comment: with me is working