# "Inside & Outside" volumes IE glass within glass (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, volumetrics

How can we manage "glass" interfaces which have a different volume (absorption) on each side of the interface. For example colored liquid within a colored glass.

I understand that to manage correct IOR we must configure the interface to have IOR= (IOR of medium normals away from)/(IOR of medium normals face towards)

However this does not solve the issue of needing to define a different volume for each side of the interface.

I tried mixing absorption shaders with backfacing as a factor but it does not appear to function. I'm guessing blender assumes when looking "out" of object there is only AIR so does not render volume when looking "out"(ie looking in the direction the normals face)

Comment: related links:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles 
 http://adaptivesamples.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/ and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass/35741#35741

Comment: @cegaton these links advise handling of IOR at the interface but this question is about the volume. The interface mesh needs to have an inside and "outside" volume assigned. I cannot see a way to define the "outside" volume. Usually the outside volume is AIR (aka empty) but in the case of the glass/liquid interface the outside is actually the glass (or liquid).

Comment: Can you post some of your test renders and/or node setups?