# Not clear water

Tags: rendering

i'm newbie for using 3D, especially this software. I try to learn from this tutorial https://youtu.be/xSWUa_Rbolk. this is a tutorial to make a water in a glass. but when i render my object something weird appear. did i miss something?
this is a picture and the left side was my render. thank you
[image]

Comment: did you increase the sample size?

Comment: Make sure the bottle has some thickness and the fluid is inside the borders as explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass?rq=1]

Comment: @sidar and cuoka thank you for your question and answer, from that i realize what happen to my render. so that object surface must not touch each other when apply glass effect. it solve now. cheers!