# Noise on the front side of water using Yarafay

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm rendering a tank of water using Yafaray. Everything works pretty well except I get banded noise on the front side of the water shown in the picture. [image: Rendered Image]

How should I fix it?

Comment: How are your mesh intersections, are you taking [good care of the interactions between the intervening surfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass)? Its looks like you have overlapping faces

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's a good point. I just set the boundary of the water to the same size as the inner side of the box (in x and y direction). I didn't do more to the interface. I will read the link you posted.

Comment: After I read the post of your link, I got better understanding to the interface setting. But for the interface between diffuse matter and water, how should I set it?

Comment: If a material is opaque then no need for any special setup, if its full submerged it takes care of itself, otherwise just let it intersect the water surface naturally.

Comment: So I scale the water a little bit up to let water and box have intersections. Then I get the clean rendering result. I still don't quite understand the mechanism that creates the noise. But thanks a lot!

Comment: You should post your findings below as an answer with a short but concise description of what you did and how it solved your problem. It may help others in the future