# How can I get my glass to look like this glass?

Tags: materials, light, glass

[image]  I have tried to make it look like this but I cant get the reflections with it still being see through. Could someone please help figure out how I can get my glass material to look like this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to mix a Glossy and a Glass node?

Comment: please post your current node layout

Comment: I added the node layout to the question

Comment: How are you lighting your scene?

Comment: As far as lighting I haven't put anything more than the original light that is already there

Comment: You need an environment to reflect in your glass. Tye using  an HDRi for lighting. Also maybe related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass

Comment: The reason its not see through is because you have a gray background. The 2nd picture has 1 big square light and possible a 2nd smaller one I cant tell, Plus that yellow bar of light behind it, plus the table is bouncing light. You need all the objects in the scene so they can interact with the light better. An HDRI can help. But I do not believe your 2nd pic is using an HDRI.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Light settings]

[image: Glass transparency]

You may want to check those parameters(I´m using 2.79b.6) More bounces means more light will sample through the glass. But like the friends up here suggested, we would all like to check what your material looks like first.

Comment: I added a picture of what it looks like

Comment: @Ethan - I think he meant your node set up.

Comment: Yeah, the node setup is the one in the picture I added