# refraction of arrow through glass of water

Tags: modeling, shaders

[image]

[image]

so i have been trying to simulate arrow refraction through a glass full of water where the arrow's direction is reversed. i have applied refraction BSDF to both the glass and the fluid mesh with IOR 1.45(do i need to set different IOR for the water and glass??) and the arrow refracted but was doubled!! so why this happened and how shall i get rid of it? also i don't know  why there is that black colour on surface of water and corners of glass! how to get rid of that too??

Comment: Related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass

Comment: i don't really get that issue with normals..i don't understand what is it?? i understood that i have to set different IOR for glass and water but i don't understand the calculations done ahd how i am supposed to set 3 different IOR for interaction surface of (air and glass),(air and liquid),(glass and liquid)?