# Why there are black patches visible in fluid simulation?

Tags: materials, shaders, fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

I created a fluid simulation that imitates a ship moving, creates splashes, and displaces water. I made this scene in a large-scale ocean and I've cleverly made it to imitate that the splashes that arise from the ocean using a dynamic paint canvas plane.

The problem here is that there are black patches in fluid simulation as shown in the below preview. Fluid simulation material is Glass, sharp, IOR 1.333, and ocean and dynamic paint canvas material are principled BSDF, full black base color, 0 roughness, and rest as it is. Please help... or if it is normal and okay like that please tell.

Also, the ship is not in images as I will composite it separately.

Render Preview:
[image]

Top render preview with ocean and dynamic paint canvas plane surface visible in the viewport:
[image]

Top render preview with ocean and dynamic paint canvas plane surface hidden in the viewport:
[image]

Comment: The ocean object is just a plane?

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yes, it is, with noise texture imitating ocean. Using an ocean modifier would blow my PC apart along with my house.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I suspect with a plane the *Glass BSDF* is going to let the ray pass through, and then there is no back face to bounce it back to the light source, so the ray is reported as lost (black color).

Comment: A couple of links - you might be able to work around by extruding the sides down, creating a bottom face, and using a Volume shader in addition to Surface.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv2wqwsvx-8&t=224s

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237777/110840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ocean plane looks good for deep water at this time of day.

Here's another shader to try for the splash.  You might need to put a *Solidify* modifier on the plane in your scene for it to display properly.

[image]