# Volume Absorption density of whiskey

Tags: volumetrics

In [fluid in a glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass) it mentions using a volume absorption node. Below are the settings suggested for red wine in the [answer from @gandalf](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35741/15543).

[image]

Any clues re  what settings, particularly  density, to use  for whiskey?

Comment: are you talking about bubbles within the liquid?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35731/15543