# Refractive Layer At The Neck Of A Bottle Of Beer

Tags: materials

I have been modeling some beer and I noticed this:
[image]
Where there is a layer of dark at the intersection between the bottle neck and the body of the beer.
I modeled the shape of the beer and used the glass and beer IORs for the materials, but this layer of dark is gone:

[image: Image2]

Why is this layer of dark there and why doesn't blender simulate it? (And how do I fix it?)

Comment: On the real bottle there is a sharper border between the body and the neck. But the main reason is probably the different light source. Try to adjust the lamp's parameters and position.

Comment: @FFeller How? I used a very bright bar twice the size of the beer just outside the camera. What do you suggest for the lighting of the actual beer?

Comment: Does the glass have thickness? Did you set the normals for the liquid? Read the following related links:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @susu The glass has thickness. I did set normals for the liquid pointing out. The volume absorption node doesn't have sharpness, and end up making the center of the beer darker (or redder if the color was the color of my beer) and not the intersection. It just makes the beer look dirtier.

Comment: You could achive something like that with a fresnel and a diffuse color, simulating the color of the glass close to the edges