# Why is the liquid's reflection look so weird after the render? (Blender Guru tutorial)

Tags: rendering, glass

I was doing the coffee cup tutorial that made by Blender Guru,and this happened:
The shadow looks weird when there is liquid in the cup.(Look like dimanods?)[image]
But everything looks right when there is nothing inside the cup. Don't know why is that happening.[image]
Here is my compositing.(I didn't turn on the denoising in the render properties.)[image]
Here is how it looks like in rendered view mode
[image]
The wireframe of the glass and the liquid.

Cup's wireframe[image]
LIquid's wireframe
[image]

Have a nice day.

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)  My guess is that the problem has to do with the way you made the object that is the liquid, so if you can't include your blend file please at least add a wireframe of the liquid and glass

Comment: This might be caused by less geometry at the top of water!
try adding loop cut s(ctrl+r)  at the top of water geometry.
As marty fouts said it's best to share a blend file or a wireframe it makes easy for people to look into the issue.
Have a nice day!

Comment: So I think it was the way I made the liquid is causing the problem,it has the weird flower look on the top.(Also,I add the wireframe in the question.)

Comment: Blender Guru clearly shows in the tutorial how to inset faces, make loop cuts etc. to improve the liquid, also he scales it into the cup. Your sceenshot looks like you stopped modeling before he is doing all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your liquid mesh is intersecting very slightly with the cup.  It's possible they have different render values for their *Subdivision Surface* modifiers, or a common fix (and one given by Price) you could try is scaling the liquid mesh up *very* slightly.

This intersects the liquid's outer faces into the glass completely which gets you a pretty good render.

Additionally, there are several posts on this site and others regarding the proper *physically correct* method of rendering liquids in glasses, which I will link here.

[Liquid / glass interface IOR and normals in Cycles - BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles)

[fluid in a glass - BSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass/35741#35741)

[Fluid in a Glass - Greg Zaal's blog](http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/10/19/fluid-in-a-glass/)