# rendering a (glass) bottle with a liquid in it

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, glass

I'm trying to render a soja bottle (transparent) with glass in it; but when rendering it (Cycles), it looks weird - like if the liquid was cut in bias :

[image]

My mesh looks okay.
I have a bottle that has a solidify modifier, which has a basic BSDF glass shader with a 1.53 IOR.

The liquid is another instance of the bottle, which has a boolean modifier and a displace modifier (to "inset" it).

[image]

I don't know if this is the right way to achieve this.
Since the bottle is two-sided (out and in sides); maybe the refraction is computed twice ?

Is this a correct way to render a bottle with a liquid in it, or is there some tips I should know ?

File [is here](https://filedn.eu/lDv4C27hDkbRzM3b8NHRBTz/blendswap-soy-bottle.blend) if you want to have a look.

Thanks !

Comment: Related: [fluid in a glass](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35726/fluid-in-a-glass)

Comment: @brockmann ... in this case, though, since soy sauce is nearly opaque, you could probably get away with the surface of the liquid being between the inner and outer surfaces of the glass, not bothering with the IOR calculations on the common surface? Not physically accurate, but....

Comment: I haven't fixed it.. (may pop in an answer if I have time to play with this) .. but the dark area is the reflection of the background beyond the end of the floor of your cove.

Comment: i don't know what you want to achieve with your displace modifier in liquid, but if you disable this in viewport, you got this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4z7E.jpg

Comment: @Chris The displace is to "shrink" the liquid (which is the same mesh than the bottle) inside the bottle.

Comment: @RobinBetts Absolutely right, just thought might be nice to link this one in case since gandalf's explanation is sweet.