# Why is this weird line in appearing in Glass material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, glass

I cannot understand why this weird line in appearing in my coffee

[image]

I decreased IOR of my glass and increased density of coffee. I moved light, checked if I have two materials and nothing is working.

It's still there even though I changed the camera view.

[image]

Comment: Double-check if the coffee is intersecting the cup glass at all places. You also may want to try moving the light, as it may be the light refracting through the cup walls and reflecting off the surface of the coffee

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles

Comment: @stphnl329 I checked it very carefully and it is intersecting it. I was moving the light to a various places and changing the light settings and nothing helped. I still have these two lines (this white one and black one a little lower). Going into the edit mode also didn't give me any clues because this line is not any of the edges so it has to be something with light or my materials. Thank you for the help!

Comment: From the images it looks as if it is either a reflection or refraction of the plate edge. Try hiding objects one by one and seeing if any affects it

Comment: @cegaton I checked it as well and changed IOR of glass-air and liquid-air accordingly but I am missing where can I find IOR for glass-liquid? My guess is that it calculates itself?
Thank you for the link!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos when I hide the cup the lines and disappearing but I still cannot find the idea on how to remove them. They don't look natural even though it is a reflection. I don't if I should leave it now and mask it in a Photoshop or stubbornly look for a solution ;) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @stphnl329 My liquid is as blue as it can get! That's why it is so confusing to me why it appears like this.

Comment: It is probably just the reflection of the cup edge, and should actually be there

Answer (score 1):

It just occurred to me that this is probably a case of reversed normals seeing as the entire shading of the coffee is off. A *Normal* is a line that comes off perpendicular to a plane. Blender uses these to calculate lighting off the various faces of a mesh, but if they're facing the wrong way (inside rather than outside), then the shading of the object will not look right.

To check if the normals are facing the correct direction, open the *Viewport Overlays* drop-down menu, and check *Face Orientation*. If the normals are facing the right way (as in facing in the direction the object is meant to be viewed), than the object will appear blue. If not, it will be red.

[image]

If this is the case, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode with the coffee selected, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

[image]