# Mirror-ish reflection on top face of liquid in glass cup model (Beginner)

Tags: reflection

I am making a Negroni glass and have changed the liquids base colour to an orange (#d0812e). However, the top face of the liquid remains this clear/mirror like colour. Even when putting a HDRI into the world section the top just reflects the HDRI like a mirror. I imagine this is an easy fix but I am super new to Blender and haven't been able to figure it out.

- Random detail, when I change the view to be birds eye you can see the red liquid (Image attached) [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to reality! :)  Sorry. not entirely fair to say that... but have a  look at a real-life glass of colored liquid below bright, relatively blank lighting. That's not to say the PBR is doing  a perfect job.. one aspect you might want a look at is the [liquid-glass interface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2824/35559)

Comment: Thank you that article really helped :)

Comment: np :) Also, you may want a meniscus around your ice-cubes... that might make an interesting question in its own right..