# Improving the look of my glass and water

Tags: shaders, lighting, glass

I have worked on and improved my glass since last time and even added some water to it:

[image]

The glass on the left has 'water' in it, and the glass on the right is an empty glass.

I am still however, having some weird patches at the bottom of both glasses. I suspect this must be because the bottom of the glass concaves upwards slightly (I was advised to not have flat glasses) and I've missed a step somewhere or have unsuitable values in my nodes.

The glass with the liquid also has light interacting with it weirdly. What parameters should I modify/change to improve it?

I have attached the blend file below if you'd like to investigate:

[image]

Comment: That looks pretty good, a few issues I noticed, firstly the glass with water looks like the waters top blends into the glass, this is because your water object doesn't have a top surface. secondly the jagged refraction at the bottom of the glasses, is because the bottom of your glasses (and water object) have the "star burst" shape (what happens when you subdivide tris) so I'd suggest adding an extra edge loop there and shrinking and smoothing out the "star burst" portion so it doesn't cause that.

Comment: thirdly what is exaggerating the previous issue is that your water object is scaled up penetrating into the glass allowing them to effect each others refractions, making that jagged "star burst" shape way more noticeable than it would otherwise be. and finally not so much an issue just a suggestion add a tiny little bit of volume scatter into your water shader (added along with your current vol absorption) this is slightly darken your water to help distinguish it from your glass.

Comment: For strict PBR,  check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2824/35559)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do water, depending on the context, I've tried something that is a mix between the *Glass* node and a *Glossy* with a *Layer Weight* as factor, it will create additional reflections, and also a *Volume Scatter* instead of the *Volume Absorption*. I'm sure that there are better solutions but it creates the illusion:

[image]