# Texture painting by lightsource

Tags: shaders, lighting, texture-painting

I'm trying to simulate the grit blast treatment of the turbine blade. I can repeat all movements that grit blasting machine doing but I need the traces of treatment on the surface of the blade.  The best way of simulation of nozzle is spotlight with controled cone angle. Is there a way of changing color of texture in the place where spotlight directed? [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-change-object-materals